Angular http client not able to call the backend API hosted in aws private subnet
I have launched two EC2 instances in a public and private subnet respectively. I also created a VPC peering between both.
I also had successfully called the API (from EC2 in public subnet) and getting the response return by API (EC2 in the private subnet).

However, the angular hosted on the public subnet was not able to call the API. Just wonder anyone has encountered this issue previously?

I start the angular via ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=4200
I also added the INBOUND rule on the security group in private subnet to allowed port 4200 and 3000. But somehow the angular still cannot call the API.

